# Python3: writing info from a text file to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, os.walk

I have multiple directories each with multiple files in:

```
Ce  
+---top.txt
+---X0.0        
|     |  
|     +---Y0.0  
|     |     |
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.0.dat
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.0.out
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.dat
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.out   
|     +---Y0.05
|           |
|           +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.0.dat
|     |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.out
|           +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.05.dat
|           +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.05.out
+---X0.05
      |  
      +---Y0.0  
      |     |
      |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.0.dat
      |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.0.out
      |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.dat
      |     +---X0.0Y0.0Z0.05.out   
      +---Y0.05
            |
            +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.0.dat
            +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.0.out
            +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.05.dat
            +---X0.0Y0.05Z0.05.out
```

I am attempting to extract the relevant information from the '.out' files and write it to a csv file. For this I have devised the following code:

```
import os
import csv

with open('results.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Filename', 'Optimisation Achieved?', 'Final Energy', 'Number of Defects', 'Defect Charge', 'M-L Centre X', 'M-L Centre Y', 'M-L Centre Z', 'Defect X', 'Defect Y', 'Defect Z', 'Defect Energy']) 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.out'):
                file = os.path.join(root, filename)
                with open(file, 'r') as reader:
                    opt_cnt=0
                    for line in reader:
                        s=line.strip()
                        if s=='**** Optimisation achieved ****':
                            opt_cnt+=1
                            if opt_cnt==1:
                                opt1='Y' + str(opt_cnt)
                            if opt_cnt==2:
                                opt2='Y' + str(opt_cnt)
                            else:
                                opt2='N'
                        elif s.startswith('Final energy='):
                            Final=s[18:31]
                        elif s.startswith('Total Number of Defects'):
                            Number=s[31]
                        elif s.startswith('Total charge on defect'):
                            Q=s[-4:]
                        elif s.startswith('Defect centre'):
                            centrex=s[21:28]
                            centrey=s[31:37]
                            centrez=s[40:46]
                        elif s.startswith('Atom/Fractional'):
                            coordx=s[40:49]
                            coordy=s[51:60]
                            coordz=s[62:71]
                        elif s.startswith('Final defect energy'):
                            Defect_Energy=s[-13:]
                writer.writerow([filename, opt1, Final, Number, centrex, centrey, centrez, coordx, coordy, coordz, Defect_Energy])
```

However, this produces the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Dropbox\Brannerite\Published   Potentials\interstitials\Grid\Ce\results.py", line 39, in 

    writer.writerow([filename, opt1, Final, Number, centrex, centrey, centrez, coordx, coordy, coordz, Defect_Energy])

NameError: name 'Final' is not defined**

[Altering the amount of indentation of the the last line in my code alters which of the variables comes up in the nameError: as the code is there are 16 indents (the same is NameError is given with 20 indents); altering this to 8, 12 or 24 gives '**NameError: name 'opt1' is not defined**]

I should say that much of this code [remove the lines relating to os.walk] has been used successfully for a different set of files (that were all in one directory).

Can anyone suggest where the error is coming from in the above code and how it can be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an `out` file that doesn't have line that starts with `Final energy=`, `Final` stays undefined. You may want to define default values for `Final`, `Number` etc variables that are defined in the loop, for example set them all to `undefined` string:

```
Final = Number = ... = 'undefined'
file = os.path.join(root, filename)
with open(file, 'r') as reader:
    opt_cnt=0
    for line in reader:
        ...
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. Each file does (or at least should) have that line - the problem was it wasn't being found because I had made the error of changing the case of some of the letters in the string. However, your answer gave me the clue of where to look - without it I wouldn't have done so...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have 2 vars Final and opt1 defined. Which is not the case in your code

```
writer.writerow([filename, opt1, Final, Number, centrex, centrey, centrez, coordx, coordy,    coordz, Defect_Energy])
```

as your code allows to define only 1 of them or opt1 or Final due to if/elif construct:

```
if s=='**** Optimisation achieved ****':
    opt_cnt+=1
    if opt_cnt==1:
        opt1='Y' + str(opt_cnt)
elif s.startswith('Final energy='):
    Final=s[18:31]
```

Maybe try defining default values upfront or change the logic applied